# Solidity debugger in VS Code

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, foundry, vscode

Is there a good Solidity debugger out there for Foundry that gives you the same UX in VS code as when debugging a node.js app? Like local/state variables inspection, breakpoints, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a Solidity debugger called "Solidity Visual Auditor" that provides a similar debugging experience to VS Code for node.js apps.

It allows for local and state variable inspection, setting breakpoints, and stepping through code.
Solidity Visual Auditor is a helpful tool for developers working with Solidity on the Foundry platform.

Comment: There isn't an extension in VS code with that name. There is one for Consensys, but when you go to it, it gives you this one, which is not a debugger: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tintinweb.solidity-visual-auditor